# TrueType to C Array

Tags: c, parsing, text, low-level, typography

I am writing a low level C app, and I'm planning on using an array to store my fonts.

The problem is, the font I'd like to use is in TrueType format. How shall I:

1. Convert TTF to a large sized, B&W, bitmap
   font without any kind of AA (not strictly programming
   related);
2. Parse the B&W bitmap font into a C byte array.

What format should I use for the bitmap? Should be simple enough that me, a beginner programmer with little over a year of experience can write a parser to store it in said array.

I don't want to use external libraries, and I'd like to keep C Std. Lib. usage to a minimum. It's for a college project and I want to write everything myself.

Comment: I'm going to sleep, I'll accept/comment answers tomorrow. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the most professional or cleanest, but here's what I'd do in your situation:

- Choose a monospaced font and a size where each character is an integral number of pixels.
- Open GIMP (or your favorite image editing program) and make an image that's `font_width` pixels wide and `font_height*96` pixels tall.
- Make a text element anchored at the upper-left corner containing `<space> <newline> ! <newline> " <newline> # <newline>` ... (i.e. all the ASCII glyphs).
- Save it as an uncompressed image format that's easy to process, like PNM.
- Load it into an array of type `uint8_t [96][font_height][font_width]`.

Comment: Not clean, but I liked your idea the most. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Win32 GDI APIs to write bitmaps: create a bitmap, print a letter, use `GetPixel` to read it. Serialize to .c file.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Freetype](http://www.freetype.org/). It can provide you with data you can use for your bitmap creation.